# Representing objects with negative coordintaes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, coordinates, scene

I have to represent Objects on the screen (let's say circles). I already have a list of those, and their coordinates are also given.

The problem is that the given objects can also contain negative values of x and y. And as we know  in JavaFX the coordinate system goes from the left upper corner starting with 0, and basically has only positive values.

Is there any way to somehow get to see the circles that are also on the negative side?

Can it be solved with scrolling?

Comment: Depending on what you are actually trying to do, and what actual behavior you want, simply using a [`Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) to contain your shapes might be all you need. Or, if you use a `Pane` of some kind, you could just set the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the pane.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding in your own set of 'axes' (whether you show them or not on the screen is irrelevant, but it helps to think of them as such), with an origin (0,0) somewhere in the middle of your screen. If your canvas is 500x500, then your origin would be at (250,250). Then, for all your objects, their 'raw' coordinate can be shown on screen via adding the origin coordinate to it. So, a circle with a center at (-10,50) will be shown at (240,200).

If you still have objects offscreen, I would suggest adding in a mouse listener to add a click and drag type of scroll. Here's how to do that in pseudocode:

On Mouse Down, record the screen coordinate when the mouse was pressed and save it to a variable dragStartPoint or something.

On Mouse Up, record the screen coordinate when the mouse was released after a drag, name it dragEndPoint. Subtract dragStartPoint's coordinates from dragEndPoints, and apply their difference to your origin point's coordinates and the rest of the objects.

Notice, you can still start with your origin at (0,0) if you want as long as you have this click and drag scrolling! Good luck, and if you need example code for the mouse listener I can edit this post later.

You can also make this a more responsive by changing everything onMouseMoved instead of onMouseUp, you just have to make sure the mouse is pressed in onMouseMoved so it doesn't scroll all the time.